# Adding border to the Mat Calander

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-datetimepicker

I am trying to add border around mat calander , but unable to do it as , I am not able to find the exact class which will affect the look of the mat calander exactly that I needed like >>>>> . [image]

I have tried to do exactly like same given above with class

```
.mat-form-field-flex {
    border: 1px solid ;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/bajnpdvmbqo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.css

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily using appearance="outline" in mat-form-field tag like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **::ng-deep** selector like this

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex {
border: 1px solid gray; }
```

check below link for more reference
https://ngrefs.com/latest/styling/ng-deep-selector